# HtmlUnit - How show iframe content

Tags: javascript, iframe, htmlunit

I'm creating a web crawler using HtmlUnit. The website I'm working on is full of iframes, but HtmlUnit does not load the content of the iframe automatically.

How can I make it happen, or set the iframe content via DOM?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's the other site that loads into your iframe? In that case you cannot get content because of [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).